# What is IDA and how does it help me view .so files?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiling, shared-objects, ida

So I'm reverse engineering an Android app and looking for a string that I know is inside the app, somewhere.

I've decompiled the app.

I've done a search for the string in all files, looking for the string, but nothing is returned.

I was told to use "IDA" to view all of the files with ".so" extension.

What is IDA? Am I going about this right?

Answer (score -1):

IDA is a disassembler and debugger: [Look at this](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)